# Is it possible to do a conditional on a callback that involves a where call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

On my `Membership` model, I have the following callback:

```
after_create :setup_connection,
```

I would like this to only be run if this method returns true:

```
  def connection_exists?(membership)
    Connection.where("membership_id = ? OR invited_membership_id = ?", membership.id, membership.id).count > 0 ? true : false
  end
```

It seems that the typical `:if and :unless` expect a column/symbol or a Proc.

Not sure how to convert the above into a workable Proc.

How can I modify this callback to work for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your membership model:

```
def connection_exists
  Connection.where("membership_id = ? OR invited_membership_id = ?", self.id, self.id).count > 0 ? true : false
end
```

And set it as:

```
after_create :setup_connection, if: Proc.new { self.connection_exists }
```

Comment: I did an `unless` with that same condition...but the callback seems to still be executed when that `connection_exists` returns true. Thoughts?